# Passing unknown enum type to method with vararg enum parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection

I have a method that I found through reflection that takes in a `vararg itemFlags: ItemFlag` parameter. I have the enum type, `ItemFlag`, which I also found through reflection. How do I go about invoking the method with a typed array of `ItemFlag` if the type is unknown? I've tried creating an `Array<Any>` with the enum instances and passing that as the argument but it throws `IllegalArgumentException` with a message of `argument type mismatch`.

My code (trimmed for example):

```
val itemStack = ...
val itemMeta = ...

val enumClass = Class.forName("org.bukkit.inventory.ItemFlag")
val enumInstance = (enumClass!!.enumConstants as Array<Enum<*>>).first { it.name == "HIDE_ENCHANTS" }
val addItemFlagsMethod = ItemMeta::class.java.declaredMethods.first { method -> method.name == "addItemFlags" }

// addItemFlags only parameter is vararg flags: ItemFlag
addItemFlagsMethod!!.invoke(itemMeta, arrayOf(enumInstance))
```

Comment: what did you try so far? where is your code?

Comment: even though I explained what I've already tried, and that it didn't work, I've added my example code to the original post.

Comment: why do you access it via reflection? You need to pass an array of the same type to that method... if you have no access to the type (I assume that is your problem otherwise I see no reason for reflection), you can use something like: `listOf(enumInstance).toTypedArray()` to get the array you require...

Comment: I have to access it via reflection so my app is compatible with several versions of an API (Bukkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
val arr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(enumClass, 1)
java.lang.reflect.Array.set(arr, 0, enumInstance)
addItemFlagsMethod!!.invoke(itemMeta, arr)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. Can you possibly fix the link to the documentation?

Comment: @JoelEvans Fixed, no idea what happened there.